# FreeCodeCamp Challenge: Explain error message?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Please see my (non-optimal) solution for the following challenge:

> Return the number of total permutations of the provided string that
> don't have repeated consecutive letters.

The expected result is *2640*. However, I'm getting a maximum call stack size exceeded error!

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
> at findFactorial:14:24
> at findFactorial:21:14
> at findFactorial:21:14
> at findFactorial:21:14
> at findFactorial:21:14
> at findFactorial:21:14

```
    function permAlone(str) {
        var final, factorial, repeated, i;
        repeated = str.match(/([a-z])(?:.*)(\1)+/g); 
        if (str.length < 2) {
            return 1;
        }

        // should return ["aa", "ff"]
        if (repeated[0] === str) { 
            repeated[0] = repeated[0].split('').sort().join('').match(/([a-z])(?:.*)(\1)+/g);
            repeated = repeated.reduce(function(a, b) {
                return a.concat(b);
            });
        }
    
        function findFactorial(n) {
            if (n < 0) {
                alert("No negative numbers accepted.");
            }
            if (n === 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            return n * findFactorial(n - 1);
        }

        factorial = findFactorial(str.length); // 7! = 5040

        for (i = 0; i < repeated.length; i++) {
            i++;
            if (repeated.length === 1 && repeated.join("") !== str) {
                final = factorial - findFactorial((str.length - 1)) * findFactorial(repeated[0].length);
            } else if (repeated.length > 1 && repeated[i-1].length>2 || repeated[i].length>2) {
                final = findFactorial(repeated[i].length) * findFactorial(repeated[i - 1].length);
            } else {
                final = factorial - ((findFactorial((str.length - 1) * repeated[i].length) * (findFactorial(str.length - 1) * repeated[i - 1].length))) + (findFactorial(str.length - 2) * findFactorial(repeated[i - 1]) * findFactorial(repeated[i]));
                //  final = 5040 - ((6! * 2!)*2) + (5! * 2! * 2!);
            }
        }
        return final;
    }
    permAlone('abfdefa'); // should return 2640
```

Comment: This occurs when you are in an infinite loop.  Check out your recursion to make sure it is exiting when it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tibsar pointed you and me in the right direction. Passed "aa" or "ff" findFactorial will keep calling itself until the stack blows. You could add bulletproofing to findFactorial beyond the check for negative input (check for non-integer input). But meanwhile, I found the offending line in your code: [you will need to scroll right to see the bad part and what needs to change, you forgot .length twice]

```
                final = factorial - ((findFactorial((str.length - 1) * repeated[i].length) * (findFactorial(str.length - 1) * repeated[i - 1].length))) + (findFactorial(str.length - 2) * findFactorial(repeated[i - 1]) * findFactorial(repeated[i]));
```

it should be,

```
                final = factorial - ((findFactorial((str.length - 1) * repeated[i].length) * (findFactorial(str.length - 1) * repeated[i - 1].length))) + (findFactorial(str.length - 2) * findFactorial(repeated[i - 1].length) * findFactorial(repeated[i].length));
```

As it happens, this does not seem to give the correct answer to the challenge, but it does resolve the error you asked about.